# Unique elements between two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, list

i have just started using Pandas and i'm amazed by how flexible it is but i've hit a roadblock and need some help

I have a data frame Df:

```
  | Contract | Box1       | Box2         |
  | A        | Red,White  | Red,Black    |
  | B        | Red        | White,Black  |
  | C        | Black      | Black        |
```

I wanted to find entries that are **not common** between Box1 and Box2 and store them in two new separate columns so that the output looks something like this:

```
  | Contract   | Box1_unique | Box2_unique|
  | A          | White       | Black      |
  | B          | Red         | White,Black|
  | C          | -           |  -         |
```

I tried

```
Df['Box1_unique'] = Df['Box1']-Df['Box2']
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: Could you please use `df.to_dict()` and add the data to your question? Will be easier to recreate your dataframe and give the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set.difference` in list comprehension with `zip` - ordering should be changed:

```
df[['Box1','Box2']] = [(','.join(set(a.split(',')).difference(b.split(','))), 
                        ','.join(set(b.split(',')).difference(a.split(','))))
                       for a, b in zip(df['Box1'], df['Box2'])]
print (df)
  Contract   Box1         Box2
0        A  White        Black
1        B    Red  Black,White
2        C
```

Or generator comprehension with `not in` statement - ordering is like original:

```
df[['Box1','Box2']] = [(','.join(i for i in a.split(',') if i not in b.split(',')), 
                        ','.join(i for i in b.split(',') if i not in a.split(',')))
                       for a, b in zip(df['Box1'], df['Box2'])]
print (df)
  Contract   Box1         Box2
0        A  White        Black
1        B    Red  White,Black
2        C
```

Last for set `-` use:

```
df[['Box1','Box2']] = df[['Box1','Box2']].mask(df[['Box1','Box2']].eq(''), '-')
print (df)
  Contract   Box1         Box2
0        A  White        Black
1        B    Red  White,Black
2        C      -            -
```